# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endfor' T ENDFOR php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, content-management-system

I copied a source code from youtube, i did it properly with mysql, but there's showing a big problem woth "endif"

```
<?php
<?php for($x = 1; $x <= $pages; $x++); ?>
            <a href="?pages=<?php echo $x; ?>&per-page=<?php echo $perPage; ?>"><?php echo $x;?></a>
        <?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: Why nest `<?php` tags?

Comment: What is your problem? Which error occures? What should this piece of "code" do?

Answer (score 1):

Change **for(...);** to **for(...):**

```
<?php for($x = 1; $x <= $pages; $x++): ?> //<-- change ; to :
        <a href="?pages=<?php echo $x; ?>&per-page=<?php echo $perPage; ?>"><?php echo $x;?></a>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: @Michael are you sure? `<?php for(.....); ?> <?php endfor; ?>` show error **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endfor' T ENDFOR** however `<?php for(.....): ?> <?php endfor; ?>`  run property. I don´t know what is do rest of code because it´s not a question.

Comment: @Michael I can´t comented your answer but is not recomended mix html inside php code It is not a recomended conduct by an good programmer

Comment: Executing the above code returns a HTML500 code. I didn´t took the time to figure out the problem.

Comment: regarding the Mixup... this is a small sniplet, if you want it the correct way you should use templates, but as far as you already mentioned the rest of the code is missing.